# Why did a mod threaten me with a suspension for "continually pinging a mod" whereas I was simply replying comments they made on one of my questions?

Tags: discussion, moderators, account-suspension

On [this question](https://web.archive.org/web/20230430220016/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/170373/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-when-adding-files-to-an-existing-ar?noredirect=1#comment158246_170373), a moderator wrote (emphasis mine):

> On the main site, comments should not be used to have extended discussions. Please use the [Stack Exchange](https://web.archive.org/web/20230430220016/https://stackexchange.com/) features properly. Also, **refrain from continually pinging a mod. That behavior is inappropriate and might lead to getting a suspension for abusing the [Stack Exchange](https://web.archive.org/web/20230430220016/https://stackexchange.com/) features.**

I was simply replying to comments they made on my question.

Why did a moderator threaten me with a suspension for "continually pinging a mod" whereas I was simply replying comments they made on one of my mquestions? Aren't users allowed to reply to moderators' comments?